# VirtueMart adds category and sub category name into page title

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, title

Site currently adds the name of the category and any sub category to product page titles.

For example, for this URL `http://example.com.au/baby-clothes/boys-rompers/example.html`, I have the following title: *Example page title | **Boys Rompers/Sets** | **Baby Boy Clothes** | Example site name*.

How can I remove these from the page title, so its left with just the page title and site name?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what version of Joomla you are using, but there are several extensions for title management:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/title-management

This will help you with modifying the title.